# Solving ODEs in several variables for a single function?

Tags: differential-equations

Consider differential equations such as

```
eq[1] = x  a1 f[x, y] + y a2 D[f[x, y], x] + a3 D[f[x, y], x, x] == 0
eq[2] = y b1 f[x, y] + x b2 D[f[x, y], y] + b3 D[f[x, y], y, y] == 0
```

where `f[x,y]` depends on two variables, but each ODE has derivatives with respect to either `x` or `y`, but not both. `DSolve` can deal with each ODE separately:

```
DSolve[eq[1], f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> [image]

```
DSolve[eq[2], f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> [image]

However, when I try to provide both ODEs to `DSolve` at once

```
DSolve[eq[1] && eq[2], f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

Mathematica simply returns back the input and refuses to solve it.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to have Mathematica produce a single output that satisfies both ODEs at once? If so, how should I do this properly?

Comment: How is this different from  having 2 equations and one unknown? `eq1 = x^2 + 3 x + 3 == 0;
eq2 = x^3 + 3 x + 3 == 0;
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, x]`  what should the solution be?  or `eq1 = x^2 + a x + b == 0;
eq2 = x^2 + c x + d == 0;
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, x]`

Comment: @Nasser I'm not sure what the solution should look like, since I'm interested in finding it. However, this is different from the two equations with one unknown, since `x` and `y` derivatives are not the same. One could try to plug the solution `f[x,y]` of the first ODE into the second ODE and solve the second ODE for the unknowns `C[1][y]` and `C[2][y]` to find the result, but these equations seem too complicated...

Comment: You are trying to find a needle in a haystack. To solve the PDE it is necessary to formulate a boundary value problem. Then unknown functions are determined. You can add two equations `eq[1]/a3+eq[2]/b3` or subtract them  `eq[1]/a3-eq[2]/b3` and then there will be two equations - elliptic and hyperbolic type, respectively. And depending on whether you pose the Dirichlet problem or the Cauchy problem, you need to choose an elliptic or hyperbolic equation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Curious, I thought getting a general solution of two linearly independent functions since the ODE is second order, I should be able to fix the boundary conditions after the fact, no?

Comment: @Kagaratsch We must first set the boundary value problem or the Cauchy problem. Otherwise, the function is not defined. Do you solve the problem of quantum mechanics?

Comment: @Kagaratsch  I believe that there is no general solution for this system.